# Problem with Save-Load system in batch-files

Tags: batch-file

I've been attempting to make this huge batch-file program and during one of the sessions of making it, I realized at some point the program would need to perform two separate tasks. Therefore I made another Mini program to help my big program, it was all going great until I started needing to transfer information from the big program to the small one.

I though it would be no problem and I just made a .sav file that saved all the necessary information for the smaller program there! After this, I made the code for the small program in the way that it would load up all the information from the .sav file. I though I was all good and clear but whenever I loaded up the program, none of the necessary data loaded with it

Instead of it loading the data such as per say `var=2` it loaded data like `var=`, meaning that my code just gave me "ECHO IS OFF" errors often, and sometimes even crashed

I have tried looking all over the internet for a solve but I couldn't find anyone else with the same problem
I hope you guys can help me with it, Here is about how my code looks without the actual var/ Location names

Big Program:

```
(
echo %var1%
echo %var2%
echo %var3%
) > "Location\name.sav"
```

Small program:

```
< "Location\name.sav" (
set /p var1=
set /p var2=
set /p var3=
)
```

I have no typos or errors, I checked like a million times
If anyone knows how to solve this, Please help~

Comment: If you open name.sav in a text editor, does it contain the correct information?

Comment: What is displayed in the console window when you remove the redirection part `> "…"` from the big program?

Answer (score 1):

The code snippets you have posted seem ok.
What is missing is where you assign values to the variables.
If you assign these values within the same () codeblock then you cannot echo these values as in your code.
You will have to use delayed expansion of variables to use echo with the uptodate values.
See setlocal /? for details on the use of delayed expansion.
After you have enabled delayedexpansion you can change the `echo %var1%` to `echo !var1!` to get the values to show.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way of doing this, which requires only that you use a predetermined string of one or more characters at the beginning of each variable name.

The following example uses the string `var` at the beginning of each variable name, and hopefully shows you how it works, just copy it and try it:

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

Rem Make sure there are no existing variables in the environment named beginning with var.
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set var) 2> NUL"') Do Set "%%G="

Rem Code which defines your variables each beginning with the string var.
Set "var1=some value"
Set "var2=another value"
Set "var3=different value"

Rem See the now defined var variables
Set var & Pause

Rem send each of your variables and their values out to a sav file.
Set var 1> "myfile.sav" 2> NUL

Rem Undefine your variables again.
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('"(Set var) 2> NUL"') Do Set "%%G="

Rem check that the variables no longer exist.
Set var & Pause

Rem Get your variables back from the sav file.
For /F UseBackQ^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ("myfile.sav") Do Set "%%G"

Rem See the variables now defined again.
Set var & Pause
```

Answer (score 0):

along the same lines of Compo's answer, however it's easier still to save to a batch file that you can call, and if you use some macros to automate the saving of variables as you define them.

```bat
@Echo off
::: To safely define macros.
 SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DISABLEdelayedExpansion
rem ::: %Save% macro is built into the definition of each def/vartype macro to autosave variables when defined
rem ::: - def Vartypes: [[/S] standard string.] [[/P] Set /P input prompt] [[/I] Set /A Integer variable]
 Set User="%TEMP%\%~n0_!#Sv.name!_sav.bat"
 Set Save=(For /F "Tokens=1 Delims==" %%i in ('Set #Sv.') Do (If not "!%%i!"=="" Echo/Set "%%i=!%%~i!"))^>%User%
 Set "Loc=(Set "#Sv.Loc=@"&Title !#Sv.Loc!)&%Save%"
rem :::  usage: %def/S:VAR=Varname%VariableValue
 Set "def/S=For %%n in (1 2)Do If %%n==2 (Set "#Sv.VAR=!str!"&%Save%)Else Set str="
rem :::  usage: %def/P:VAR=Varname%Output prompt string
 Set "def/P=For %%n in (1 2)Do If %%n==2 ((For /L %%v in (1 1 10)Do if "!#Sv.VAR!" == "" (Set /P "#Sv.VAR=!promptstr!: "))&%Save%)Else Set promptstr="
rem :::  usage: %def/I:VAR=Varname%=Equation | %/A:V=Varname%+=IntegerVal | %/A:V=Varname%+=!IntegerVaR!
 Set "def/I=For %%n in (1 2)Do If %%n==2 (Set /A "#Sv.VAR!sum!"&%Save%)Else Set sum="
rem ::: Required to execute macros.
 SETLOCAL ENABLEdelayedExpansion
:Welcome
rem ::: first variable should be name as save macro uses the name to reference user save.
 If Exist "%TEMP%\%~n0_*_sav.bat" (Echo/Existing Users:&Echo/&(For /F "Delims=" %%G in ('Dir "%TEMP%\%~n0_*_sav.bat" /B')Do For /F "Tokens=2 Delims=_" %%o in ("%%~nG") Do  < Nul Set /P "=[%%o] ")&Echo/)
 Set /P "#Sv.Name=Enter your name: "
 If Exist %User% (Echo/[C]ontinue / [D]elete?&For /F "Delims=" %%O in ('Choice /N /C:cd')Do If /I "%%O"=="C" (Goto :Load)Else (Del /P %User% & Goto :welcome))
:Load
 CALL %User% 2> Nul 
 If Not "!#Sv.Loc!" == "" (Goto :!#Sv.Loc!)
Pause
:Start
 %Loc:@=Start%
 %def/I:VAR=dollars%+=!random! %%1000 + 500
 Echo/You have $!#Sv.dollars!.
:end
%Loc:@=end%
Echo/User demo Save contents.
 TYPE %User%
Endlocal & Endlocal
```